# Error - Cannot call method 'sendRequest' of undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i am trying to build a RSS Fetcher Extension using this tutorial -

http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2011/11/how-to-build-a-chrome-extension

But I guess this is a little bit old and Google already made some changes. The Extension for download there doesn't work at all. I've solved many errors to make it work but im stucked in this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'sendRequest' of undefined

This is my **popup.html** file where the error is.

```
function fetch_feed() {
chrome.extension.sendRequest({'action' : 'fetch_feed', 'url' : 'http://spfc.terra.com.br/rss/news.xml'}, 
    function(response) {
        display_stories(response);
        }
    );
}

function display_stories(feed_data) {
    var xml_doc = $.parseXML(feed_data);
    $xml = $(xml_doc);
    var items = $xml.find("item");
    $('#popup').html('<img src="logo.png" id="logo" onclick="open_item(\'http://spfc.terra.com.br/\'); window.close();" /><br clear="all" />');
    items.each(function(index, element) {
        var post = parse_post(element);
        var item = '';
        var class2 = '';
        if (index >= localStorage['unread_count']) {
            // // console.log('visited');
            item += '<div class="post read">';
        }
        else {
            item += '<div class="post">'
        }
        item += '<span class="tag">' + post.tag + '</span>\
                    <a href="' + post.url + '">\
                        <div id="' + post.id + '" class="item" onclick="open_item(\'' + post.url + '\');">\
                            <img src="' + post.img + '" width="107" height="60" />\
                            <h4>' + post.title + '</h4>\
                            <span class="description">' + post.description + '...</span>\
                        </div>\
                    </a>';
        item += '</div>';
        $('#popup').append(item);
    });
}
```

By the way i have also an error in **background.html**, in this part:

```
function fetch_feed(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data) {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
          var data = xhr.responseText;
          callback(data);
        } else {
          callback(null);
        }
      }
    }
    // Note that any URL fetched here must be matched by a permission in
    // the manifest.json file!
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send();
}   


function onRequest(request, sender, callback) {
    if (request.action == 'fetch_feed') {
      fetch_feed(request.url, callback);
    }
}


chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);
```

Is the same error but with another property:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onRequest' of undefined

P.S. i've tried to find the solution here before ask and couldn't. Wait for some help to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

`chrome.extension.sendRequest` is deprecated you should use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` for message passing to background script

You can see the full api at: [Chrome Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I replaced sendRequest by sendMessage and onRequest by onMessage (in background.html) and i get the same error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'sendMessage' of undefined**

Comment: @ThiagoDosReis Sorry I wrote the function with an error it should be `chrome.runtime` instead of chrome.extension for `sendMessage` and `onMessage`